# Operand type clash: table is incompatible with user defined table type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have created one user defined table type. And also I have created one stored procedure to access the tabular data that is passed from .net application.   The Stored procedure has one parameter of table type (data type).  That way I can dump the Tabular data into the SQL Physical table with some additional data.

**Here is a sample user defined table data type**.

```
CREATE TYPE UT_EMP_TYPE AS TABLE
(
     First_Name varchar(100) Null,
     Last_Name  varchar(100) Null,
     Date_Created Date Null
)
```

**Here is the sample Stored Procedure that has a parameter that accepts table data type.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_APPEND_EMP
     @EMP_DETAILS UT_EMP_TYPE READONLY
AS
BEGIN
     IF Object_ID('temdb..#Temp_EMPDETAILS') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tEMP_EMPDETAILS
     INSERT INTO #Temp_EMPDETAILS
     SELECT * FROM @EMP_DETAILS;

     SELECT * FROM #Temp_EMPDETAILS
     
END
```

**Here is how I am testing the Stored procedure with some sample table data.**

```
    Declare @tempEmp as table (FNAME Varchar(100), LNAME Varchar(100), Date_Created Date)
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('ABC', 'AAA', '2021-06-15')
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('DEF', 'DDD', '2021-06-16')
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('GHI', 'GGG', '2021-06-14')

EXECUTE USP_APPEND_EMP @tempEmp
```

When I execute the stored procedure the system is throwing error.

*Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure USP_APPEND_EMP, Line 0 (Batch Start Line 0 ]*

*Operand type clash: table is incompatible with UT_EMP_TYPE*

Please can you check for me.  I appreciate your help
Thank you.

Comment: The message is pretty clear -- you have to declare `@tempEmp` as type `dbo.UT_EMP_TYPE`, not an arbitrary `table`. Note that table types do *not* use structural equality, so just having the same columns of the same types in the same order doesn't make table types compatible.

Comment: Try `Declare @tempEmp as UT_EMP_TYPE` ...

Comment: Brilliant it worked like a charm.  I have assigned variable to table type instead of arbitrary Table.
Thank you so much    #stu.  and #Jeroen Mostert
for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @tempEmp as UT_EMP_TYPE
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('ABC', 'AAA', '2021-06-15')
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('DEF', 'DDD', '2021-06-16')
    INSERT INTO @tempEmp values('GHI', 'GGG', '2021-06-14')

EXECUTE USP_APPEND_EMP @tempEmp
```

Everything is correct only your call is wrong...
Please call stored procedure as above. You are creating a separate table which is causing the issue.